# Parsing day/time format

Tags: python, parsing, datetime, time

Having some trouble working with time in python. I'm trying to parse a maintenance window string and work out if we're in a maintenance window. So far I have the below but doesn't seem to work.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from datetime import datetime
import re
import time

maintenance="sat:02:00-sun:03:00"

# Split start time and end time
main_start, main_end = re.split(r"-", maintenance)

main_start = datetime.strptime(main_start, "%a:%H:%M")
main_end = datetime.strptime(main_end, "%a:%H:%M")
now = datetime.now()

if now >= main_start and now <= main_end:
    print 'In maintenance window'
```

I think the problem is that I'm only wanting to concentrate on the day of week and time but its taking into account the year and month.

Struggling to work out how to achieve this.

I also didn't know if `datetime` would be able to take the input day of week (`%a`) as all lowercase.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: "but doesn't seem to work"  How so?

Comment: It doesn't print even if I change the maintenance window to a day/time that it should

Comment: How did you try to debug it? Have you tried to `print(main_start, main_end)`? `datetime`'s default date is `1/1/1900`. How do you expect it to know what `'sat'` are you referring to? You need to somehow calculate the date of the "closest" Saturday (in this example) to today's date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dateutil`, like this:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import *
>>> main_start, main_end = maintenance.split("-") # don't use re for this
>>> main_start_time = parse(main_start.replace(":"," ",1))
>>> main_start_time
datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 13, 2, 0)
>>> main_end_time = parse(main_end.replace(":"," ",1))
>>> main_end_time
datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 7, 3, 0)
```

Now, observe that these are datetimes relative to 0h00 today, and because today is Sunday, the next relative datetime for a Saturday is next week. So you will need to fix cases where `main_start_time` comes a week after `main_end_time`, like this:

```
>>> from dateutil.relativedelta import *
>>> main_start_time - relativedelta(days=7)
datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 6, 2, 0)
```

So, to perform your test,

```
>>> import datetime
>>> main_start_time -= relativedelta(days=7)
>>> if main_start_time <= datetime.datetime.now() <= main_end_time:
        print 'In maintenance window'
```

Comment: I had to add the delta into an if statement as sometimes it threw back incorrect output.
`if main_start_time >= main_end_time:
    main_start_time - relativedelta(days=7)`

Comment: No, that should be `-=` not `-`. *Subtract* 7 days from `main_start_time`, not  *calculate the difference from* `main_start_time` *and then throw it away.*

Comment: Ah, that's what I meant, 
`if main_start_time >= main_end_time: main_start_time -= relativedelta(days=7)`